# Bootstrap Vertical Center contents in row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple table-esque layout in Bootstrap 3 as such (it's a "property grid):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div id="propGrid">
      <div class="row pgTable">
        <div class="col col-md-12">
          <div class="row pgGroupRow">
            <div class="col col-md-12 pgGroupCell">Editor</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row pgRow">
            <div class="col col-md-5 pgCell">Font<span class="pgTooltip" title="The font editor to use">[?]</span></div>
            <div class="col col-md-7 pgCell"><input type="text" id="pg0font" value="Consolas" <="" input=""></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row pgRow">
            <div class="col col-md-5 pgCell">Font size</div>
            <div class="col col-md-7 pgCell"><span class="ui-spinner ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content"><input type="text" id="pg0fontSize" value="14" style="width:50px" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="20" aria-valuenow="14" autocomplete="off" class="ui-spinner-input" role="spinbutton"><a tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-up ui-corner-tr"></a><a tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-down ui-corner-br"></a></span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row pgRow">
            <div class="col col-md-5 pgCell">Font color</div>
            <div class="col col-md-7 pgCell"><input type="text" id="pg0fontColor" value="#a3ac03" <="" input=""></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row pgGroupRow">
            <div class="col col-md-12 pgGroupCell">Plugins</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row pgRow">
            <div class="col col-md-5 pgCell">jQuery<span class="pgTooltip" title="Whether or not to include jQuery on the page">[?]</span></div>
            <div class="col col-md-7 pgCell"><input type="checkbox" id="pg0jQuery" value="jQuery" checked=""></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row pgRow">
            <div class="col col-md-5 pgCell">modernizr<span class="pgTooltip" title="Whether or not to include modernizr on the page">[?]</span></div>
            <div class="col col-md-7 pgCell"><input type="checkbox" id="pg0modernizr" value="modernizr"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row pgRow">
            <div class="col col-md-5 pgCell">Framework<span class="pgTooltip" title="Whether to include any additional framework">[?]</span></div>
            <div class="col col-md-7 pgCell"><select id="pg0framework"><option value="None">None</option><option value="angular" selected="">AngularJS</option><option value="backbone">Backbone.js</option></select></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row pgGroupRow">
            <div class="col col-md-12 pgGroupCell">Other</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row pgRow">
            <div class="col col-md-5 pgCell">iHaveNoMeta</div>
            <div class="col col-md-7 pgCell"><input type="text" id="pg0iHaveNoMeta" value="Never mind..." <="" input=""></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row pgRow">
            <div class="col col-md-5 pgCell">I am read only</div>
            <div class="col col-md-7 pgCell"><label for="pg0iAmReadOnly" title="Label types use a label tag for read-only properties">I am a label which is not editable</label></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've been trying with no success to vertically center the contents of the left column against the height of the right column.

Check out the Code pen at 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrvNaV
and take a look at the last row in particular.

I've tried adjusting the padding, but since the content of the right column has variable height, that doesn't seem like a good solution.  The line-height adjustment I usually use seem to fail for similar reasons.

Any ideas on how to vertically center the contents of both columns, given it's row height (row height being determined by the content height in either column or a particular row)?

Comment: JSFiddle (with CSS) please

Comment: There is a code-pen link in the description with the CSS/HTML.

Comment: Saw it. See my reply.

Comment: I now notice your html needs fixes. Check it here: https://www.onlinewebcheck.com (then edit question and tag me)

Comment: It won't work until your HTML isn't set right. Check it with the tool I linked

Comment: Also check bootstrap Docs for rules on rows and columns: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: THanks @AllDani for the link to that tool.  Fixed the errors at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrvNaV .

Comment: Great. now read the bootstrap docs for rules specific to their CSS, and we'll be set to work on this. Good chances it'll "solve itself" after this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vertically centering float-based content is very problematic. There are a handful of hacks to do it (using transformations or negative bottom margins), but it is far easier to use display table or flexbox for the layout.

Change the row to flexbox like this:

```
.pgRow {
  background:yellow;
  display: flex;  /* make the row a flex container */
  align-items: center; /* vertically center each flex item in the container */
}
```

Be sure to remove the `height` from the `.va`! Generally, you should not set heights on containers in CSS; doing so will only introduce a load of other problems.

For more options, check out http://howtocenterincss.com/. To get a handle on flexbox, check [out this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) article on CSS Tricks. To really get a handle on all these things and how they work together (shameless plug alert), checkout [my book](https://www.manning.com/books/css-in-depth).

Comment: great website ;)

Answer (score 4):

I added `align-items-center` to my `row` class.

Example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The example's from the Bootstrap docs [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#vertical-alignment)

Comment: For anyone looking at this in 2022, this one should be the accepted answer.